# Strip an XML object of its object status, and save the value contained inside

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have an object which contains an array, which contains an array, which contains an object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [path] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [0] => 44.6451471575972
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

What I need to turn that into is this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [path] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 44.6451471575972
                )
        )
)
```

Basically I need to get rid of that object, but save the value in that object. Using PHP, how do I do this?

EDIT: Here the code I am using to create the array:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('/Users/jasonburton/Sites/walkabout/csv-importer/xml/'.$old_route_id.'.xml');

$nodes = $xml->xpath('/markers/line/*');

$json = new stdClass;
$json->path = array();

foreach($nodes as $node){       
  foreach($node->attributes() as $index=>$value){
    $values[] = $value;

    if(count($values) == 2){
      $json->path[] = array($values[0], $values[1]);
      unset($values);
      $values = array();
    }
  }         
}

print_r($json);
```

$value is what contains the SimpleXMLObject that needs to be converted into the value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type cast $value with string: $values[] = (string)$value;